# Oracle - Convert number 8 digit number to date

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an oracle database where the dates are recorded as 8 digit number as for example:

```
59696580 which represent '01/07/2013  00:00:00'
59696610 which represent '01/07/2013  00:30:00'
```

Would someone know how to convert this 8 digit number into a date in Oracle SQL?

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be the number of minutes since 1900.

Comment: it Look like 1 = 1 minute

Comment: So, the number represents the number of minutes since 12/30/1899 01:00:00??

Comment: what do you mean convert? Lets say in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might depend on the timezone, but looks like this number is the number of minutes since `12-30-1899 1:00:00`, given the dates you want them to represent.

In order to get the date, you can just use the addition `+` operator to add a number of days to that base time. Given your number represents minutes, you can divide by 1440 to find out how many days do those minutes represent:

```
to_date('12-30-1899 1:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:Mi:SS') + (59696580/1440) 
to_date('12-30-1899 1:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:Mi:SS') + (59696610/1440)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/13354)

Comment: +1 Not the correct answer as OP want, but very logical. **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/13343)**

Comment: Might depend on the timezone, but got the results the OP wanted by using `12-31-1899 1:00:00` as the base time. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/13351).

Comment: This is great. When I run this query though (to_date('12-30-1899 1:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:Mi:SS') + (59696580/1440)) I don't get the time, just the date as '01-Jul-13'. Any ideas why?

Comment: Might be related to your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` variable. This variable controls how your session transforms `DATE`s into `CHAR`s for displaying. The `DATE` is right, just [change `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/682596) or give a custom format to it with `TO_CHAR(date, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:Mi:SS')`.