# Cannot convert number to date

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have problem converting number column to date, I did the following

```
SELECT to_date('12-30-1899 1:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:Mi:SS') + (createDate/1440) 
FROM table_A;
```

and got the query result

```
10/17/5826 17:18
```

The month and date including hours and seconds is right but the year is different I got 5826. Its also the same for the other rows i got different results for year. I did follow some examples on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543219/oracle-convert-number-8-digit-number-to-date). But still got wrong result. Can anyone help on this thanks.

The samples below are createDate column values:

```
1300844909778
1302831103113
1303210978316
1396963615616
```

Comment: Probably, createDate is number of milliseconds since [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29), but you are assuming it to be something else.

Comment: How do you know everything except the year is right - you already know exactly what these values are supposed to represent?

Comment: hi alex, sorry for that statement i meant to say that months, day etc are being displayed correctly but the value they represent is not right.

Comment: @dimas Do you know what the expected result for each createDate value is?

Comment: hi joseph, yes its a date format. From the answers of APC and Eat a Peach they could be right that the 13 digits are milliseconds since Unix epoch. I just have to prove if their theory is right.

Answer (score 3):

Date arithmetic in Oracle assumes *days*.  As it stands you are dividing a very large number by `1440` and adding *that number of days* to your starting date.  That's why you're getting results in the far future.

So what value does `createdate` represent?   It's clearly not an actual date.  Your choice of `1440` as denominator suggests you think it's meant to be "number of minutes" but if the dates are so far out of expectation that is not it either.

---

I thought could be values represented [in the Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) because the numbers start with `13`.  Except that they're way too big.  Current Unix timestamps should be ten digits.  You've got thirteen digits.

Could they be Unix epoch plus milliseconds?

I have created a SQLfiddle to test this theory.  Treating the first ten digits of your `createdate` values as seconds and adding that number to the Unix date produces sensible dates.  [Check it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a590e/2).

So the theory holds water.  But I doesn't help with your query.  Adding two dates together doesn't make any sense.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  If your're looking for an interval you need to subtract the earlier date from the later one.

Comment: hi APC for all effort, this one is not clearly documented on our end and am still new to the system. But based on the code its just using a Date function and parse dates to this format we're seeing

Answer (score 0):

The createDate could be the number of milliseconds. It is just a guess. If so, then maybe this helps:

```
SELECT to_date('12-30-1899 1:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:Mi:SS') + (1300844909778/(1000*60*60*24))
FROM dual
/

3/21/1941 2:48:30 AM
```